# Changing 'hover()' to 'on("vmouseover")', ruins script and outputs 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Trying to make video thumbnails with previews on hover. Everything works like this great, but I'm trying to switch the `.hover(function()` on line 7, into `.on("vmouseover", function()`, for better mobile hovering. But once i do this simple change, the script just outputs 'undefined' into the `<img>` source.

Ford F250s for reference.

Code with hover():

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slideshowIntervalId = 0;
 var slideshowIndex = 0;


 $(".thumbnail").hover(function() {
  var slideshowImages = [
   "http://www.509autos.com/images.aspx/id-554270619/2017-ford-f250-619-p1.jpg", 
   "https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg",
   "https://file.kbb.com/kbb/vehicleimage/housenew/480x360/2018/2018-ford-f250%20super%20duty%20regular%20cab-frontside_ft2sdr1801.jpg",
   "https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/1005159/13302137/thumb/945421006.jpg"
  ];
  var $image = $(this);
  $image.addClass("hover");
  $image.data("original-src", this.src);
  slideshowIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
   slideshowIndex = ++slideshowIndex % slideshowImages.length;
   $image.attr("src", slideshowImages[slideshowIndex]);
  }, 1000);
 },
 function() {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  this.src = $(this).data("original-src");
  clearInterval(slideshowIntervalId);
 });

});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</body>
```

Code with on("vmouseover", .. :

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slideshowIntervalId = 0;
 var slideshowIndex = 0;


 $(".thumbnail").on("vmouseover", function() {
  var slideshowImages = [
   "http://www.509autos.com/images.aspx/id-554270619/2017-ford-f250-619-p1.jpg", 
   "https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg",
   "https://file.kbb.com/kbb/vehicleimage/housenew/480x360/2018/2018-ford-f250%20super%20duty%20regular%20cab-frontside_ft2sdr1801.jpg",
   "https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/1005159/13302137/thumb/945421006.jpg"
  ];
  var $image = $(this);
  $image.addClass("hover");
  $image.data("original-src", this.src);
  slideshowIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
   slideshowIndex = ++slideshowIndex % slideshowImages.length;
   $image.attr("src", slideshowImages[slideshowIndex]);
  }, 1000);
 },
 function() {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  this.src = $(this).data("original-src");
  clearInterval(slideshowIntervalId);
 });

});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see your `vmouseover`. Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can debug your code properly. If you don't put effort in your question, people won't put effort in their answer ;-)

Comment: PD: Ok, you done it while I was writing the comment xD nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you added 2 functions to the `on("vmouseover")` event. The `hover()` method receives two functions, one for the `mouseover` event and other for the `mouseout` event, but that's not the case for the `on()` method, as it don't listens for the "counterpart" event.

If you add 2 functions to the `on()` method, it will only run the last one function passed. This can be easily tested with `console.log()` and the Developers Tools open (PROTIP: F12):

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbnail").on("vmouseover", function() {
        console.log("asd");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("asd2"); // Only this callback is executed.
    });
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</body>
```

For it to work you have to attach both events, `vmouseover` and `vmouseout`, like this:

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slideshowIntervalId = 0;
 var slideshowIndex = 0;


 $(".thumbnail").on("vmouseover", function() {
  console.log("asd");
  var slideshowImages = [
   "http://www.509autos.com/images.aspx/id-554270619/2017-ford-f250-619-p1.jpg", 
   "https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg",
   "https://file.kbb.com/kbb/vehicleimage/housenew/480x360/2018/2018-ford-f250%20super%20duty%20regular%20cab-frontside_ft2sdr1801.jpg",
   "https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/1005159/13302137/thumb/945421006.jpg"
  ];
  var $image = $(this);
  $image.addClass("hover");
  $image.data("original-src", this.src);
  slideshowIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
   slideshowIndex = ++slideshowIndex % slideshowImages.length;
   $image.attr("src", slideshowImages[slideshowIndex]);
  }, 1000);
 }).on("vmouseout", function() {
  console.log("asd2");
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  this.src = $(this).data("original-src");
  clearInterval(slideshowIntervalId);
 });

});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/amv-prod-cad-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/media/267365/2008-ford-f-250-super-duty-4x4-crew-cab-diesel-v-8-photo-4826-s-original.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</body>
```

Comment: You can chain the event handlers for `vmouseover` and `vmouseout`.

Comment: @hev1 Yep, you can, but wanted to be more explicit about what was happening.